# How can I get notified when a paste occurs in TinyMCE editor 4.x

Tags: ecmascript-6, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE editor 4.4.3. I need to get the content of the editor when it changes in order to render a preview.

I'm hooked into the 'change' event which works well for most cases (including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) but not when you paste from the context menu of the browser.

Here is my code:

```
tinymce.init({ 
    selector:'#editor',
    height: 400,
    statusbar: false,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: ['link'],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | link |  bullist numlist outdent indent'
}).then(editors => {
    this.editor = editors[0];
    this.editor.on('change', () => this.refreshPreview());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I managed to solve it...

I had to include the **paste plugin** and bind to the **paste event** (this only fires if you include the paste plugin).

```
tinymce.init({ 
    selector:'#editor',
    height: 400,
    statusbar: false,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: ['link', 'paste'],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | link |  bullist numlist outdent indent'
}).then(editors => {
    this.editor = editors[0];
    this.editor.on('change', () => this.refreshPreview());
    this.editor.on('paste', () => this.refreshPreview());
});
```